# Access collection Genexus Item using JAVA

Tags: java, compiler-errors, genexus

I have to print some graphs using jFreeChar in Genexus.
I have already achieve to print the graphs when the variable where i get the data is a vector type, selecting in properties the dimension = Vector and Row= (number of items). In that case, I can get a element using:

```
JAVA            categoriaBar = [!&categorias!][iBar];
```

being &categorias the vector type variable and iBar a java attribute declared before.

This works, but in the real case, the information is given by SDT and this code is not working.

How can i get an item of a Collection using JAVA, i have tried the following statements and all returns a java error: "illegal start of expression"

```
JAVA            categoryLine = [!&jFreeChar1.Categories.Item(1)!];
JAVA            categoryLine = [!&jFreeChar1.Categories.Item!][1];
JAVA            categoryLine = [!&jFreeChar1.Categories!].get(1);
JAVA            categoryLine = [!&jFreeChar1.Categories.Item([!1!])!];
```

being &jFreeChar1.Categories a collection.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. What type would `categoryLine` be? In the first example, you get an individual value (int for instance); but in the second one you get an SDT. I would try writing the expression you want in GeneXus, get the individual value, and the pass it to your Java code, Not the other way arround... If you tell us the SDTs structure and what value you need to extract, it may be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what are you trying to achieve, but maybe this hint could help you: in general speaking when you are trying to use SDT data in JAVA kind of statements is preferable to use a "simple" intermediate variables. Following your example:

```
&myTempVar = &jFreeChar1.Categories.Item(1)
java categoryLine = [!&myTempVar!];
```

Just my 2cents.